# how to detect cell phone or mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a mobile website in HTML5. There is a function to detect if the device is a cell phone or not(if the device can making a call), so I can do different operation. What I want is to detect if the mobile device can making a call. Such as distinguish GALAXY Tab from GALAXY S4. How can I implement it? Thanks.

Comment: What are you planning to do if you find that the user is using a mobile? It's usually a bad idea to make decisions based on what browser the user is using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery this is how to detect the mobile device.

Comment: Thanks all replies, What I want is to detect if the mobile device can make a call. Such as distinguish GALAXY Tab from GALAXY S4.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate; mobile detection seems irrelevant, i.e. the question is how to detect a device that can make a phone call versus one that cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using pure HTML. You can get the scripts for various languages from:

**[detectmobilebrowsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)**